# Multiply part of a 3d numpy array with a constant

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I concatenated arrays `A (4, 24, 64)` and `B (1, 24, 64)` and obtained `C (5, 24, 64)`. Now I want to multiply that part of array `C` which corresponds to values from array `B` with a constant, leaving the rest of array `C` untouched. I tried

```
C = C[4,:,:]*const
```

But it multiplies all the values of `C` with the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overwrite `C` entirely, only overwrite the portion of the array to be modified:

```
C[A.shape[0]:] *= const
```

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)

A = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(4, 2, 1))
B = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 2, 1))
C = np.concatenate((A, B))
C[A.shape[0]:] *= 2
```

`A`:

```
[[[4]
  [7]]

 [[7]
  [1]]

 [[9]
  [5]]

 [[8]
  [1]]]
```

`B`:

```
[[[1]
  [8]]

 [[2]
  [6]]]
```

`C[A.shape[0]:] *= 2`:

```
[[[ 4]
  [ 7]]

 [[ 7]
  [ 1]]

 [[ 9]
  [ 5]]

 [[ 8]
  [ 1]]

 [[ 2]
  [16]]

 [[ 4]
  [12]]]
```